# Prestashop 1.7- snippet jQuery code inside templates files (jQuery is not defined)

Tags: jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How can write snippet jQuery code inside theme `tpl` files? Is it even possible?

In the last of `theme\classicChild\modules\ps_customersignin\ps_customersignin.tpl` I used jQuery code, but in `chrome console` I get `(jQuery is not defined)` message:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            alert('x');
        });


</script>
{/literal}
```

**Edit:**
also use **displayBeforeBodyClosingTag** Hook before jquery code but don't work.

```
{hook h='displayBeforeBodyClosingTag'}

{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            alert('x');
        });


</script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a typical error when the jQuery, at that point, has not yet been loaded, just add this code `$this->context->controller->addJquery();` in the method `renderWidget` of the module `/modules/ps_customersignin/ps_customersignin.php` when hookDisplayHeader`.

Example of the final result:

```php
public function renderWidget($hookName, array $configuration)
{
    if ($hookName == 'displayHeader' && method_exists($this->context->controller, 'addJquery')) {
        return $this->context->controller->addJquery();
    }

    $this->smarty->assign($this->getWidgetVariables($hookName, $configuration));

    return $this->fetch($this->templateFile);
}
```

After this you will need to attach the module to the hook displayHeader in the module positions.

Comment: This function has no effect in PrestaShop 1.7 theme. jQuery2 is register by the core on every theme.

classes/controller/FrontController.php


`public function addJquery($version = null, $folder = null, $minifier = true)
    {
        /*
        This is deprecated in PrestaShop 1.7 and has no effect in PrestaShop 1.7 theme.
        jQuery2 is register by the core on every theme. Have a look at the /themes/_core folder.
        */
    }`

Comment: I have added a change in my answer, please try now with that changes and let me know. Dont forget to clear cache.

Comment: I always clear cache and turn on debug mode. I will try it. **Important event** is that last night the snippet **jquery code worked !!!**. The `jquery is not define` still is exist `on chrome console` but jquery work very well. I don't make any important change!

Comment: I tried your new code, don't have any effect. the message `jquery is not define` is still exist. But as i said on previous comment `jquery code work` truly, even though the `jquery is not define` is appear on `chrome console developer tools` **!!!**

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of all scripts including core.js(which includes jquery) are invoked before body closing tad and you try to use it earlier. So I think it's not possible to add your script that way and need to move your code to the module controller class

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is possible. Just i'm newbie in Prestashop and looking for correct way...